# Google Sheets adding text to entire column error

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

So I am trying to add a space after each first name and i do not know how.  When i try it deletes the entire column.  I am needing to put a space after each first name in each cell, how can i do it all at once?

I am needing to go through like 1,000 records and add a space after each name in each cell. can someone help me do this quickly in google sheets.

[image]

Comment: Use simple formula in cell `D2` and drag it down `=C2&" "`

Comment: Give us access to your google sheets.

Comment: @HafizSb , can you help me with one more thing

Comment: Yes you can get help by posting new question someone will help you for sure.

Comment: @HafizSb , can you help me with my recent posted question

Comment: Yes i am sorry i did not notice.

Comment: Share your sheet link ?

Comment: Sheet is protected and share your new question link.

Comment: it is saying i cannot post a question until 90 minutes.. now click link

Comment: I can only post once every 90 min. c

Comment: Undelete the question that you have deleted and i just can view your sheet cannot edit and write comments

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1o7HNuNiyJekra1J36Okio38WMaVyV4e_gmmb_O_8mf4/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235102/discussion-between-outserved-and-hafiz-sb).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use simple formula in `cell D2` and drag it down `=C2&" "`

Answer (score 0):

Since many names are empty, it would be better to check using the IF() function.

```
IF(C2<>"", C2&" ", "")
```